# Cannot access laravel debugging

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm having a hard time connecting to the development webserver inside the container (from safari on my host machine).

Since I am using `network_mode: host` I did not expect there to be any errors.

In my `.env` `APP_URL` is set to `localhost.com` - I added an entry to `/etc/hosts` accordingly.
`Ping localhost.com` referes to `127.0.0.1` so that should not be the issue.

```
version: '3'
services:
  setup:
    image: mariadb:latest
    command:
      - mysql -u root -proot -e "CREATE DATABASE central;"
  web:
    image: waryor/laravel-8.0:latest
    volumes:
      - '..:/var/www/html'
    depends_on:
            - mariadb
            - redis
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    network_mode: host
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'central'
        MYSQL_USER: 'root'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root'
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
  redis:
    image: arm64v8/redis:alpine
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    network_mode: host
```

Starting the webserver works without any errors

```cs
root@docker-desktop:/var/www/html# php artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Wed Oct  6 00:20:54 2021] PHP 8.0.11 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
```

I've even tried using the `--host 0.0.0.0` option without any success.

Comment: Why are you using `network_mode` ? You have a lot of stuff that you should not have in your `docker-compose.yml`, for example `tty`, `network_mode`, `stdin_open`. What do you do with the `setup` service ? You can directly use `MYSQL_DATABASE` and it will create your desired database. Your volume should not be `..:/var/www/html` but `.:/var/www/html`. Can you explain why you have what you have there ? I also see you have a custom image, I recommend to use `FROM php:8.0-fpm` and add anything you need in your `Dockerfile`, so you have more control than updating an external image every time.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I am using `tty` and `stdin_open` because my container instantly exited. I also used `network_mode` because I was not able to connect to Redis. Quick search on SO said Mac does not support the bridged network driver (which is default) - so I switched to host. Using `..:/var/www/html` because I'm in a subfolder in my project `/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the ports. You don't have to use `network_mode`. Change your file to:

```yaml
web:
    image: waryor/laravel-8.0:latest
    volumes:
      - '..:/var/www/html'
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - redis
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    network_mode: host
```

By doing `- 80:8000`, you are exposing internal `8000` to external `80`, so you can go to `localhost` and done.

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks for your answer. I've also tried that before - specifying ports I get an issue with Redis (`Connection refused`). I then read (somewhere on stackoverflow) that Mac does not support the bridged network driver (which is the default afaik). This is my current [docker-compose.yml](https://gist.github.com/deibertf/bdacbd8b09fbf6a74e8a366fc2af03f9). Can you help me out?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the only way to expose ports to be accesible outside your docker is by using [`ports`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).